# turtle. Не открывается отладка, компьютер пишет ошибку

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, turtle

turtle: Не открывается отладка, компьютер пишет ошибку

```
from turtle import*
for i in 1,2,3:
    forward(50)
    left(50)
    forward(30)
    left(90)
    forward(40)
    right(90)
    forward(30)
    right(90)
    forward(90)
    right(90)
    forward(30)
    right(90)
    forward(40)
    left(90)
    forward(30)
    left(90)
    forward(50)
exitonclick()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте, так в чем ошибка? И зачем квадратные скобки?

Comment: Я проверил код, и она полностью рабочая, разве что только квадратные скобки мешают.

Comment: здравствуйте, в текстовом редакторе скобок нет у мня не открывается откладка,саму черепашку не видно

Comment: Но в коде которую вы прислали, там стоят эти же скобки

Comment: так то этих скобок нет в коде, ошибку vscode не выдает, но откладку с действиями не запускает

Comment: Отправьте скриншот пожалуйста.

Comment: странно, я вроде в вопросе приложила

Comment: В опросе его нету, только исходный код.

Comment: честно, в первый раз тут, без понятия как его приложить

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что у вас tkinter не установлен.

Comment: а как его установить?

Comment: в самом редакторе можно?

Comment: Через терминал, например. На разных линуксах по-разному. На дебиан-подобных  - `sudo apt install python3-tk`

Comment: у меня как раз дебиан, сейчас попробую

Comment: все, спасибо огромное, вы мне очень помогли)